# Taking this column of dates and grouping them 1-30, 31- 59, 60 - 89, +90, both upcoming and those dates that have passes

Tags: sql, date, grouping

[enter image description here](https://datasources/0d08b682-3425-41b4-a79b-af163286816a/details/data/table)[image]I have a dates column that I am trying to group in to specific groups. Some dates have passed other dates are in the future. I want to have group them by 1-30, 31- 59, 60 - 89, +90, so there would be 8 groups total for both those that have passed and those that are on the horizon. Below is what I have wrote so far, but I feel like I am over complicating and the more tweaks I make the more incorrect it becomes. Any insight is appreciated!

```
CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE(),`date`) >= 90 THEN '90 days past'
     WHEN DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE(),`date`) >= 60 THEN '60 days past'
     WHEN DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE(),`date`) >= 30 THEN '30 days past'
     WHEN DATEDIFF(`date`,CURRENT_DATE()) >= 90 THEN '90 days future'
     WHEN DATEDIFF(`date`,CURRENT_DATE()) >= 60 THEN '60 days future'
     WHEN DATEDIFF(`date`,CURRENT_DATE()) >= 30 THEN 'Next 30 days'
     ELSE 'Not Late'
END
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help. Please [TAG](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) your RDBMS.

Comment: @Stu Desired results would be to have these groups displayed in a bar chart

Comment: Unfortunately SQL produces a resultset of rows and columns, not bar charts.

Comment: @Stu trying to add the sample data. It is a single date column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's okay.

I would just use the same datediff for each.

> ```
> create table test (`date` date);
> insert into test values
> ( date_add(current_date, interval -90 day) ), 
> ( date_add(current_date, interval -89 day) ), 
> ( date_add(current_date, interval -60 day) ), 
> ( date_add(current_date, interval -59 day) ), 
> ( date_add(current_date, interval -30 day) ), 
> ( date_add(current_date, interval -29 day) ),
> ( date_add(current_date, interval 29 day) ),
> ( date_add(current_date, interval 30 day) ), 
> ( date_add(current_date, interval 59 day) ), 
> ( date_add(current_date, interval 60 day) ), 
> ( date_add(current_date, interval 89 day) ), 
> ( date_add(current_date, interval 90 day) )
> ```

> ```
> select `date`, 
>  CASE
>  WHEN DATEDIFF(`date`, CURRENT_DATE) <= -90 THEN '90 days past'
>  WHEN DATEDIFF(`date`, CURRENT_DATE) <= -60 THEN '60 days past'
>  WHEN DATEDIFF(`date`, CURRENT_DATE) <= -30 THEN '30 days past'
>  WHEN DATEDIFF(`date`, CURRENT_DATE) >=  90 THEN '90 days future'
>  WHEN DATEDIFF(`date`, CURRENT_DATE) >=  60 THEN '60 days future'
>  WHEN DATEDIFF(`date`, CURRENT_DATE) >=  30 THEN 'Next 30 days'
>  ELSE 'Not Late'
>  END as status
> from test
> ```
>
> ```
> date       | status        
> :--------- | :-------------
> 2021-10-12 | 90 days past  
> 2021-10-13 | 60 days past  
> 2021-11-11 | 60 days past  
> 2021-11-12 | 30 days past  
> 2021-12-11 | 30 days past  
> 2021-12-12 | Not Late      
> 2022-02-08 | Not Late      
> 2022-02-09 | Next 30 days  
> 2022-03-10 | Next 30 days  
> 2022-03-11 | 60 days future
> 2022-04-09 | 60 days future
> 2022-04-10 | 90 days future
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=98592ffc98baa84af0768a82c90e590f)*